# HBASE SHELL KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master

Tags: hbase, hdp

> ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase-unsecure/master

I am getting this error when I tried to list tables in hbase shell. I am using horton sandbox (hdp).

Answer (score 0):

Login to Ambari UI and enable Hbase. Start the same from Ambari UI